# `stanfordparser` ruby gem fails on `gsub` (TypeError) when calling from script?

Tags: ruby, stanford-nlp

I'm attempting to utilize the `stanfordparser` (`gem install stanfordparser`) in a simple ruby script, however I'm running into some issues.  I did have to install a few dependencies first (`rjb` & `treebank`), however I'm not running into a problem that I believe stems from the age of this gem and perhaps it not supporting ruby 1.9.

The error I get is:
`/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@all/gems/stanfordparser-2.2.0/lib/stanfordparser.rb:150:in 'gsub': can't convert Pathname into String (TypeError)`

It appears as though I need to modify any instances of gsub that are called like this?

```
def initialize(grammar = ENGLISH_PCFG_MODEL, options = [])
  @grammar = Pathname.new(grammar.gsub(/\$\(ROOT\)/, ROOT))
  super("edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser", @grammar.to_s)
  @java_object.setOptionFlags(options)
end
```

As per the request in the comments, `grammar` is coming in as Nil, so that is definitely a problem, however I'm not sure how to address this.

If you go to the documentation at http://stanfordparser.rubyforge.org and try following its directions in irb, you get the following results:

```
>> require "stanfordparser"
=> true
>> preproc = StanfordParser::DocumentPreprocessor.new
NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@all/gems/stanfordparser-2.2.0/lib/java_object.rb:40:in `import'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@all/gems/stanfordparser-2.2.0/lib/java_object.rb:40:in `initialize'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@all/gems/stanfordparser-2.2.0/lib/stanfordparser.rb:240:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone else had any luck getting this to work?

Comment: What is `@grammar.class`?

Comment: Hmm, yes that is indeed a problem when it comes in it is apparently Nil (NilClass)!

Comment: How about `grammar.class`? I'm thinking I'll trace the problem till we figure out where it goes wrong, you follow?

Comment: This just appears to be a nightmare to debug as it all seems to boil down to a java issue since this is built upon it.  I've, for now, decided to look into `Treat` or perhaps something else that allows me to analyze sentences and natural language patterns in a more Ruby native implementation.  Thanks though!

Comment: I think you just need to use a JVM-based ruby and your problems will disappear. Try [jruby](http://www.jruby.org), but I also agree that you should be using a MRI-based implementation, if you're more familiar with ruby.

Comment: Yep yep, thanks for trying to start on this though! :)

Comment: Definitely recommend louismullie's Treat work. But it is still largely built on Java components....